# Why is specific heat capacity a path function?

Tags: thermodynamics

Why does specific heat capacity depend on the process by which it is obtained?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of research-effort.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of research. Will make sure to post questions after putting in much more effort than I have put in here, in the future.

Comment: Ok! It is better for you;  have a nice day:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. It's a material priority.

Specific heat capacity $c$ is the heat required to raise the temperature of one kilogram of the material by 1 degree:

$$c=\frac{dq}{dT}/m$$

It is not a material *constant*, though, as it depends of the state of the material while heating. Materials at different temperatures, volumes, pressures, etc. have different $c$. But the "*path*" doesn't matter - only the current state.

It doesn't matter how you reached the state you are at. At a specific state, $c$ has a specific value.

Comment: some materials have memory and the heat capacity does depend on the path

Answer (score 1):

If you mean process as in the conditions kept constant (For example an isochoric or isobaric process), **specific heat** depends on these conditions as it is a **property of the material** itself.

Since the **same** material can behave differently even in the same conditions with just a **change in state**, this distinction is important.

Also the properties being measured are different in the two cases (**constant volume** and **constant pressure**, respectively) which later determine the final value of specific heat as well as the additional conditions it depends upon.

That is why the conditions taken matter.